# How to store List or Set for a Redis key in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis, jedis

I want to store the id of the user in the USERS key of Redis. If the list is empty or null then a new list with an id is added in that key.
If the key contains an already list then a new id should be added to that list.
I have implemented this approach using comma-separated string in this code given below:

```java
private synchronized void pushIdInRedis(String id) {
    String Ids = (String) redisClient.getValue("USERS");
    if(StringUtils.isEmpty(Ids)){
        redisClient.setValue("USERS",id);
    } else {
        Ids = Ids+","+id;
        redisClient.setValue("USERS",Ids);
    }
}
```

Can we achieve this using list? It should also be thread-safe.

Comment: Is there any specific reason for that comma separated-values ids approach? Redis provides some data types that are more suitable for that. For instance [lists](https://redis.io/topics/data-types#lists)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should take a look at `RedisTemplate` documentation. There you will find the method [`opsForList()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/core/RedisTemplate.html#opsForList--) that will return a [`ListOperations`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/core/ListOperations.html). With it, you can edit a given Redis list.